# NHibernate Linq MismatchedTreeNodeException, Simple OrderBy and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am getting a MismatchedTreeNodeException throw with the simple query below using NHibernate 3.2.0.4000. I am assuming it is a bug and if so does anyone know of a work around?

```
var result = session.Query<File>()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Author)
    .GroupBy(file => file.Author)
    .Select(author => new FileAuthor(author.Key, author.Count()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You may try to move the OrderBy method and call it after ToList. I think that is direct cause of the exception. (Linq provider is more or less a C# => SQL translator, and OrderBy before GroupBy is invalid in SELECT statement).

Comment: well after the GroupBy it fails as well with not being able to resolve the property Key. Also adding it after ToList kinda defeats doing the ordering in the database doesn't it since it would then be done in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around with your example and query in this form works fine:

```
var result = session.Query<File>()
                    .GroupBy(file => file.Author)
                    .Select(author => new
                    {
                       Key = author.Key.AuthorId,
                       Count = author.Count()
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Apparently, when you group by entity, it is possible only to project its ID and aggregations. It seems that sorting needs to be done on the client.

Used mappings:

```
 <class name="Author" table="authors">
        <id name="AuthorId" column="author_id" />

    <property name="AuthorName" column="author_name" />

    <bag name="Files">
      <key>
        <column name="author_id" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="File"/>
    </bag>

  </class>

  <class name="File" table="files">
        <id name="FileId" column="file_id" />

    <property name="FileName" column="file_name" />

    <many-to-one name="Author" class="Author">
      <column name="author_id"  />
    </many-to-one>

  </class>
```